# Jquery Class selector

Tags: javascript, jquery

I a developing an app in which I am using

```
 $("#plblAgreeProblem",".plblAgreeComment").live("click", function(){
      alert("bil");
}
```

but class selector is not working. my divs which have class="plblAgreeComment" are creating dynamically so I am using .live()

Please help me.

Comment: You know you have a syntax error right?

Comment: Right off the bat I can see a missing parenth & semicolon at the end.

Comment: `.live()` is a really bad way of handling events btw. It's just one of those jquery - functions that are easy to use, but perform aweful (of course, look up what it actually does)

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/Ghokun/M3zCa/1/ working sample $("#plblAgreeProblem , .plblAgreeComment").on("click", function(){ alert( "hey" ); });​ Selectors should be seperated by commas in the same apostrophe `"first, second"`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

IF you are using jQuery version that is newer, and includes ".on" use that:

```
$(document).on("click", "#plblAgreeProblem, .plblAgreeComment" ,function(){ 
      alert("bil");
 });
```

NOTE: Please try to bind to something closer than "document" if at all possible - like a wrapper for that section of the markup, etc. for speed issues.

Other answers cover previous versions

Here is a working example with it wrapped:  http://jsfiddle.net/MarkSchultheiss/pP6nL/

Comment: NOTE: I made the wild assumption (based on your other question) that these are two distinct selectors, not one inside the other.  If that is incorrect, we improve this if you post the markup.

Answer (score 2):

Question isn't real clear. For selectors, try using the following.

```
$("#plblAgreeProblem, .plblAgreeComment").live("click", function(){
      alert("bil");
});
```

or

```
$(".plblAgreeComment").live("click", function(){
      alert("bil");
});
```

Comment: [-1 for NOT suggesting to NOT use live](http://jsperf.com/jquery-live-vs-delegate-vs-on). :P

Comment: @RepWhoringPeeHaa. Bad call, it's the OP who uses `live`! please revert it!

Comment: He could be using an older version of jQuery since he didn't list his version. I'd say bad judgement on your part. .on() is only for jQuery 1.7+

Comment: @ChristopherMarshall You can suggest using `.delegate` if he is using older version of jQuery

Comment: @ChristopherMarshall so what about delegate?

Comment: @RepWhoringPeeHaa is not that live is wrong or whatever, it's just deprecated in new jQuery versions (1.7 >). It's recommended to use .on http://api.jquery.com/on/.

Comment: @RepTrollingPeeHaa delegates fine as well. I listed live() as that's what the author was using, and it does indeed work for older versions of jQuery.

Comment: @axcdnt It is wrong! Have you seen the benchmark. That's just wrong.

Comment: @ChristopherMarshall sorry for being trigger happy :) You're right

Comment: If you @GNi33 can show me the evidences, I'm better believe it.

Comment: it's a handler bound to the `document` - element and delegates from there. do i really need to say more?

Comment: @RepWhoringPeeHa Excellent link. Book marked in my devlinks folder. Thanks!

Comment: @RepWhoringPeeHaa now I saw it. While I was putting my words here, all the answers haven't loaded. Looks like you've really tested it. I'm gonna check in details.

Comment: @RepWhoringPeeHaa. You messed this thread... anyway `live` is that bad as you may think. `0.02ms` instead of `0.01ms` isn't important. and that is the case in most scenarios. (But I hate `live` uses as well...)

Answer (score 1):

First you should know that `live` is deprecated in the current jQuery release, and you should use `on` instead.

That said, your selector `$("#plblAgreeProblem",".plblAgreeComment")`, will search for element with the `#plblAgreeProblem` `id` inside elements with the `plblAgreeComment` `class`. Is it the selector you meant to write?

Another note, `id` must be unique, meaning there can't be more then one element in the page with the same `id` attribute.

ohh.. and you forgot the `);` in the end of the `live` function:

```
$("#plblAgreeProblem",".plblAgreeComment").live("click", function(){
      alert("bil");
});
```

Comment: @user1334569. Can you give me the HTML structure you have? is the element you want to attach it the event has the `id` `plblAgreeProblem` and it exist inside an element with the  `plblAgreeComment` `class` ???

Answer (score 0):

if your element with the class "plblAgreeComment" is inside the of the node "#plblAgreeProblem" try using diffrent selector instead :

```
 $("#plblAgreeProblem .plblAgreeComment")
```